# Expectation of Maximum Number

Tags: probability, sequences-and-series, expected-value

Let the i.i.d. binary variables $B_{1}, B_{2}, \ldots$ with $P(B_{k}=1)=\beta$ and $P(B_{k}=0) = 1-\beta$, with $\beta \in (0,1)$.  Define the variable $M$ as follows: $M = \max\{k\geq 0: \prod_{i=0}^{k}B_{i} = 1\}$.

The problem is to find the expected value of $M$, $\mathbb{E}[M]$.

Given feedback, this reflects to the variable $M$ following the geometric distribution, where $M$ is the largest integer before the first success, thus, $E[M] = \frac{1}{1-\beta}$.

Comment: I'll have to check the computations, but you've got the skeleton of the proof spot on. Having said that, have you heard of geometric random variables, because they're useful in this question?

Comment: Thanks Sarvesh for this recommendation and spotting this! Yes, $M$ is seen as the first integer where we have failures until the first success. This follows the geometric distribution, thus, $E[M] = 1/(1-\beta)$, and that's all?

Comment: Indeed, that should be all, @Christos. So you need to see what's off with the computation, because there should not be a $\beta^2$ on the top.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback!

Comment: You are welcome!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I presume you mean $M=\max\{k\ge 0: \prod_{i=1}^k B_i=1\}$, i.e. the product is taken from $1$, not zero, with the convention that if $B_1=0$ then $M=0$.
You can compute the pmf of $M$ directly:
\begin{align}
\mathbb{P}(M=m) &= \mathbb{P}(B_1=B_2=\dots=B_m=1, B_{m+1}=0) \\
&=\mathbb{P}(B_1=1)\mathbb{P}(B_2=1)\cdots\mathbb{P}(B_m=1)\mathbb{P} (B_{m+1}=0) \\
&=\beta^m(1-\beta).
\end{align}
Now
$$\mathbb{E}M=\sum_{m=0}^\infty m\mathbb{P}(M=m)=\sum_{m=0}^\infty m\beta^m(1-\beta)=\beta(1-\beta)\sum_{m=0}^\infty m\beta^{m-1}=\beta(1-\beta)\cdot \frac1{(1-\beta)^2}.$$